# when to use d3.transition().each()?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the [Object Constancy](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/), I'm quite confusing with the code of 'change' event:

```
var menu = d3.select("#menu select")
    .on("change", change);

function change() {
  clearTimeout(timeout);

  d3.transition()
      .duration(altKey ? 7500 : 750)
      .each(redraw);
}
```

why use d3.transition().each(), not transition.call()? which I think will trigger the redraw() function every time I change the option.

After switching to call(), I lost the animation, the graph instantly switch to the end of the animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> d3.transition().each()

select the object you want to translate and translate it each one of the object, it like append motion on each object one by one so you will see the animation

**example**

your function will select an object

- *1 move to 2 
   end show to svg 
   2 move to 3 
   end show to svg*

> transition.call()

if you using call without selecting the object it will translate all object to end of result, because it will select the group of object and running a function and returning a result to it, so you will not see the animation

**example**

your function will select all the object

- *1 move to 2*  
  *2 move to 3*  
  *end show to svg*

that is the flow